# how to kick a user in agora.io?

Tags: agora.io

im trying to make it possible for a room host to kick a user, im using the rest api to kick a user, when i send a request with the following body:

```
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> actionOnUser(String action, Long channelId, String userId) {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    Map body = new HashMap<>();
    body.put("appid", agoraConfig.getAppId());
    body.put("uid", userId);
    body.put("time", 0);
    body.put("cname", channelId.toString());
    body.put("ip", "");
    String[] privileges = { action };
    body.put("privileges", privileges);
    Mono<String> agoraResponse = webClient().post().uri("/dev/v1/kicking-rule").bodyValue(body).retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class).doOnSuccess(response -> {
                logger.info("kicking-rule response status:" + response);
                completableFuture.complete(true);
            }).doOnError(onError -> {
                logger.info("kicking rule failed" + onError);
                completableFuture.complete(false);
            });
    agoraResponse.subscribe();
    return completableFuture;
}
```

i get a 200 OK response with an id of the kicking rule, but the user isn't being kicked, how can i fix this?

Edit: apparently agora doesnt accept strings as uid, had to switch to int which is unfortunate because i preferred to use UUID, but this fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

agora doesnt accept strings as uid, had to switch to int which is unfortunate because i preferred to use UUID, but this fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

For implementing kick user from call functionality you can use Agora RTM SDK.
For ref:- https://www.agora.io/en/blog/muting-and-unmuting-a-remote-user-in-a-video-call-web/

Also, you can use your custom WebSocket.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32924028)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).